# Building a Server/Client application in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I built a fairly simple program that watches a folder, manipulates files as they are added, and gives a simple progress view of whats going on. The folder is watched via a subclass of NSOperation that passes information in an NSDictionary to my progress view, via the NSNotificationCenter.

Now I need to break things up and run the watched folder/processing part on my server, and build a client to monitor the progress from multiple workstations. My problem is I don't know how to accomplish this and my searches aren't really helping me.

It seems I'm getting a lot of out dated solutions (WebObjects, Portable Distributed Objects) or incomplete information. It seems like I'd want to use NSStream to pass data back and forth, but everything I find on NSStream looks like it's set up for client side because it's looking for an IP address. What would be the best way to go about setting up both a server, and a client to connect to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) for something like this.  Since (I assume) you are writing this software for BSD (Mac OS X and iPhone are both BSD) you can use BSD C sockets, or an Objective-C wrapper for this.  One good library for a client is [CocoaAsyncSocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/).  I personally have written a lightweight Objective-C socket class for TCP networking called [SocketKit](https://github.com/unixpickle/SocketKit).  Usage of this library is something as follows:

```
// open a connection
SKTCPSocket * socket = [[SKTCPSocket alloc] initWithRemoteHost:@"SERVER_IP" port:SERVER_PORT];
// write data
[socket writeData:someData];
// read data
NSData * someData = [socket readData:4];
// close the socket
[socket close];
[socket release];
```

From a server standpoint, you can listen on a port using the `SKTCPSocketServer` class:

```
SKTCPSocket * aSocket = nil;
SKTCPSocketServer * server = [[SKTCPSocketServer alloc] initListeningOnPort:1337];
@try {
    [server listen];
    while ((aSocket = (SKTCPSocket *)[server acceptConnection]) != nil) {
        // do something with aSocket
        [aSocket close];
    }
} @catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception : %@", e);
}
[server stopServer];
[server release];
```

Of course using TCP sockets means writing your own network protocol.  A simple example would be sending a four byte length field, followed by the data of an NSDictionary or something of that nature.  This could allow you to accomplish something similar to a very basic Distributed Objects system.

Comment: Didn't mean to leave this question dead for the last couple of days. Have just been busy and haven't gotten back into this project. Thanks for the info I'll take a look at both CocoaAsyncSocket and SocketKit it sounds like this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: CocoaAsyncSocket turned out to be what I needed. I'm having a little problems getting data to write to the connected socket as events happen... But right now I'm getting an initial read upon connection so I'm sure there is something I missed in the documentation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Why not take a look at [Bonjour](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Introduction.html) for zero-configuration networking (i.e. so you don't have to find the IP address of your server)?

Since Bonjour is also supported on Windows and iOS (iPhone/iPad) you can even make your app multi-platform (e.g. server on Windows and Mac client or vice versa) or even have an iPhone act as a client of your server (don't know if this makes sense in your case but I'm just suggesting).

Answer (score 0):

This, unfortunately, is a place where Cocoa is pretty weak. Forget about WebObjects (Apple has). You probably should forget about Distributed Objects. There isn't really a built-in client/server solution on Mac. iOS has some decent peer-to-peer stuff, but it's still pretty useless for client/server.

My recommendation is to use a simple REST API. Build your server with [cocoahttpserver](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/). Build your client with `NSURLConnection` or [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). Keep it simple. I like JSON for the protocol. [YAJL](https://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc) has worked well for me, but for something really simple, there are lots of options.