# How does Instashare extend AirDrop on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, airdrop

I'm looking to replicate the Instashare functionality (for a simpler, more specialized task, that of exchanging notes between multiple people who are in close proximity to each other).

I'm not sure where to start with this, both from an architectural stand point, but also from a development stand point.

What I assume so far is that I would need to create an internal network between 2 devices (e.g. make all devices both clients and servers), then keep some sort of a connection opened on all of them.

Is this correct? Could it be a better way to do this? What frameworks could I use for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [GKSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [GKSessionDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSessionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/GKSessionDelegate) ([Tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/bluetooth-connectivity-with-gamekit/)) for sending the files over Bluetooth back and forth. For sending over just Wifi you would use TCP and something like [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) and/or [SocketKit](https://github.com/unixpickle/SocketKit).

BTW, Seems like a great weekend project. Kudos for wanting to tackle it ;)

Other related question on SO:

[Building a Server/Client application in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047250/building-a-server-client-application-in-cocoa)