# Portforwarding on IOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, networking, tcp

for my iPhone app i'd like to make all incoming tcp connections to port 1000 of my iPhone/iPad (for example IP: 10.1.2.10) to be forward to the port 1000 on host 10.1.2.250.

can someone help me?

Comment: So, would your app turn the device basically into a firewall/router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use TCP and something like [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) and/or [SocketKit](https://github.com/unixpickle/SocketKit).

Other related question on SO:

[Building a Server/Client application in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047250/building-a-server-client-application-in-cocoa)

Comment: i have a service runnung on this port on my server. some webpages asks for this services, so i need a way to forward the requests.